# Why will Google Analytics not allow our URL?

Tags: google-analytics

In Google Analytics we're trying to add a property for each website of a WordPress multisite network. It works well for all of the sub-site but one. In the Default URL field we used the following:

- `www.mywebsite.no/` - works
- `www.mywebsite.no/nurse` - works, as does a few other sub-sites
- `www.mywebsite.no/doctor` - doesn't work

In the last case we get the following error:

> Value is not a valid domain. (e.g. example.com, www.example.com)

We can't change the name of the sub-site but GA just won't accept the URL. Why is this and what can we do to solve this?

Comment: Had a look for this - seems to be a recent bug. You can track it [here](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/analytics/DJjNJ24RByM).

Comment: Thanks! Hopefully they'll do something about it very soon - our client isn't very happy about it as I'm sure a lot of others aren't either.

Comment: No problem, likely so - looks like an active thread/problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround to this by disabling the validation in your browsers dev tools.

Ulrich Lamb has blogged about the workaround:-

- [Page 1](http://www.socialmediamake.com/wp/google-analytics-value-is-not-a-valid-domain/)
- [Page 2](http://www.socialmediamake.com/wp/google-analytics-value-is-not-a-valid-domain/2/)
- [Page 3](http://www.socialmediamake.com/wp/google-analytics-value-is-not-a-valid-domain/3/)

Page two contains the fix. Why a blog would split an article as short as this into three pages is beyond me but I included the links to each page as they aren't easy to spot on this blog.

This should allow you to add the `/doctors` property in Google Analytics now (as we all know with Google, it could take months to rectify this bug).

Comment: Thanks @Geoff. The same workaround was mentioned in Dan's link above, so we've been able to track the site for about a month now. Pretty clever, though you'd think they'd be more keen to fix stuff like that.